# minifilter driver | tracking changes in files

Tags: windows-kernel, minifilter

What I'm trying to achieve is to intercept every write to a file and track the changes within the file. I want to track how much different the file content before and after the write.

So far in my minifilter driver I registered to IRP_MJ_WRITE callbacks and can now intercept writes to file. However I'm still not sure how can I obtain the content of the file before [preoperation] and the content after [postoperation].
The parameters that I have within the callback functions are:
PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS, PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA and I could not find anything related to the content of the file itself within these.

Comment: I've never written a minifilter, but I'd imagine you might use some combination of:  
(1) register for notification of file open, and when that occurs, issue your own read operations (IRP_MJ_READ) to obtain the initial file content  
(2) as you receive each IRP_MJ_WRITE, read in the corresponding initial content (if any) before passing down the write  
(3) determine when the file is closed (might be tricky?) and then go read any content that hasn't been modified, if you care about that.

Comment: `FLT_PARAMETERS` in `PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA->Iopb` will provide you required parameters of that IRP. Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544673(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

These are the operations that could change data in a file:

1. Modifying the file: **IRP_MJ_WRITE**, **IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION** ( specifically the **FileEndOfFileInformation** and **FileValidDataLengthInformation** information classes), **IRP_MJ_FILE_SYSTEM_CONTROL** ( specifically **FSCTL_OFFLOAD_WRITE**, **FSCTL_WRITE_RAW_ENCRYPTED** and **FSCTL_SET_ZERO_DATA** fsctl codes).

As for the content of the file itself that you just need to read it yourself.
If you mean the buffers as they are being written for example, check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/flt-parameters-for-irp-mj-write) out to find out more about the parameters of **IRP_MJ_WRITE** in the callback data. Esentially the buffer is at **Data->Iopb->Parameters.Write.WriteBuffer/MdlAddress**

Make sure you handle that memory correctly otherwise it will result a BSODs.

Good luck.